# TypeScript treating object as empty type instead of defined interface

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a TypeScript project where I have defined an interface called Theme which has a property called typography. The typography property is supposed to have a dynamic set of properties based on an enum called TypographyVariant. Here's my code:

```
export type TypographyVariant =
  | 'label-large'
  | 'label-medium'
  | 'label-small';

export interface Theme {
  typography: {
    [key: TypographyVariant]: {
      lineHeight: string;
      fontSize: string;
      letterSpacing?: string;
      fontWeight?: number;
    };
  };
}

const theme: Theme {
  typography: {
    'label-large': {
      lineHeight: '20px',
      fontSize: '14px',
      letterSpacing: '0.1px',
      fontWeight: 500,
    },
    'label-medium': {
      lineHeight: '16px',
      fontSize: '12px',
      letterSpacing: '0.5px',
      fontWeight: 500,
    },
    'label-small': {
      lineHeight: '16px',
      fontSize: '11px',
      letterSpacing: '0.5px',
      fontWeight: 500,
    },
  }
};
```

My code editor is treating the `typography` object inside `theme` as `{}` type instead of what I have defined in `Theme` interface.

The problem is that when I try to define the theme object, my code editor is treating the typography property as an empty object instead of the dynamic set of properties defined in the Theme interface. I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current types define `typography` such that it can only contain keys from `TypographyVariant`, but if I understand correctly you're requiring any `typography` to define *all* the variants.

Defining `typography` using a `Record` would be a good way of doing this:

```js
export interface Theme {
  typography: Record<TypographyVariant, {
      lineHeight: string;
      fontSize: string;
      letterSpacing?: string;
      fontWeight?: number;
    }>
}
```